# Concatenating a control source yields #Type! error

Tags: ms-access, report, concatenation

I have generated a report based on a query. I have a text box that I am trying to use to concatenate three of the values together for ease of readability. The fields are: `[CREATOR]`, `[TYPE]`, `[SERIAL_NUM]`, and I want the output result to be something like:

> Organization A, Spreadsheet, Copy 1

When I set the record source to just `[CREATOR]`, it populates for every record. However, when I set the record source to

```
=[CREATOR] & ", " & [TYPE] & ", " & [SERIAL_NUM]
```

the final result for every record is #Type!

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Show us the schema

Comment: What do you mean? The fields are all text fields out of the same query.

Comment: If they are all text fields in the schema then I suggest you try different combinations in your expression until you can reproduce the failure with a minimum expression. for example, try =[CREATOR] & ", " & [TYPE]  then try = [TYPE] & ", " & [SERIAL_NUM] and see that works and what fails.

Comment: Also make sure that the name of the textbox is not Creator, type or serial_num.

Comment: @AVG That fixed the problem instantly! I changed the textbox name and it worked. I have no idea why that is a problem though, can you explain?

Comment: Also, feel free to put that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @SandPiper Sure, when you name a control (in this case textbox) the same as a field name, but the control is not bound to that field, then use it in a formula, Access can't determine whether you are referring to the field or the control, so it just gives up. Usually, it displays #Name, but in your case it was #Type. Please mark answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the name of the textbox is not Creator, type or serial_num